# On the post method how to gets a list of display properties

Tags: node.js, post, request-promise

Example POST URL (with display properties):

```
https://api.hubapi.com/crm-objects/v1/objects/line_items/batch-read?hapikey=demo&properties=name&properties=quantity&properties=price
```

Example POST BODY:

```
{
  "ids": [
    9845651,
    9867373
  ]
}
```

Node syntax

```
var request = require("request-promise");
const { ids } = req.body;

    console.log("ids::", ids);

    const result = await request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `https://api.hubapi.com/crm-objects/v1/objects/line_items/batch-read`,
      qs: {
        hapikey: "demo",
        properties="name"
      },
     
      body: {
        ids,
      },
      json: true,
    });
```

The problem is, can not set the **qs display properties**, I need to collect **name, quantity, price** properties information, how to set them on node syntax? my following syntax not working

```
 properties=["name","quantity","price"]
```

Comment: I guess this is wrong `properties="name"`, you have define it inside an object so it must be like `properties: "name"`. Can you check it once?

Comment: I need more than one property informations, as I describe on question, I need properties:["name","quantity","price"]

Comment: I mean will this works? `properties: ["name","quantity","price"]`, you can define equal to (=) in the key and value pairs, you have to define is as `key:value` when defining inside an object.

Comment: thanks for the syntax issue, I replace the symbol =  with : but it's not working, I don't know why it's not working, base URL work on postman

Comment: is `properties: "name"` this working? i mean if you send a single property are you getting the response?

Comment: Yes, I get the response for the single properties: "name"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231453/discussion-between-red-and-shamim).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead of `properties=["name","quantity","price"]`

```
const properties = ['name', 'quantity', 'price']

const qs = ['hapikey=demo&']
properties.forEach((key) => {
  qs.push('properties=' + key + '&')
})
console.log(qs.join(''))
//this gives: hapikey=demo&properties=name&properties=quantity&properties=price&
```

And later

```
const result = await request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `https://api.hubapi.com/crm-objects/v1/objects/line_items/batch-read`,
  qs: `${qs.join('')}`,
  body: { ids },
  json: true,
})
```

So it will give querystring as `hapikey=demo&properties=name&properties=quantity&properties=price`